# Python 3 and PEP style guide for exposing dictionary key value pairs to globals()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep

I could not find a PEP references to the following convention:

```py
def dict_to_var(dictionary:dict) -> None:
    for variable, value in dictionary.items():
        if variable not in globals():
            globals()[variable] = value
```

which *assumes* that every key in `dictionary` is a (variable name legal) string (although in python `dict` keys can include things like `tuple`s and exposes those string values as variables into the `globals` context (as exposing it to `locals()` inside the function would not make these values accessible outside that function call).

For example:

```py
example = {'a': 'string', 'b': True}
dict_to_var(example)
print(a, b)
# 'string', True
```

I am assuming for clarity one should not do this, and if one is too lazy to write `dict[var]` then to explicitly expose the variables needed via `var = dict[var_name]` .

However, I would appreciate it if someone could find PEP basis for this.

Comment: This is both outside the scope of PEP 8 and rather bad style.

Comment: This kind of dynamic updating makes it difficult to reason about code, so it's best avoided unless you _really_ need such magic.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, right that is what I thought... I just encountered it and wanted confirmation that it should be avoided

Comment: that is _bad_. it will populate/pollute the global state (even if the dict-keys are ok'ish as variable names) with maybe some, maybe none, maybe all things from your dict. chaos reigns. _shiver_

Comment: Just imagining a wonderfully terrible dictionary, destroying all the built in functions: `{'len': 0, 'max': 1, ''min': 2, 'abs': -3, ...}` etc.